# first_or_create generates SystemStackError: stack level too deep error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having an hard time trying to understand why `first_or_create` gives me the following error.

On my Rails 4.2.0 app I have a model named Activity

```
class CreateActivities < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :activities do |t|
      t.string :name, :null => false

      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :activities, :name, :unique => true
  end
end
```

From IRB when I look for the first record with name equal *all* I correctly get nil (table is empty)

```
irb(main):004:0> Activity.where(name: 'all').first
  Activity Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `activities`.* FROM `activities` WHERE `activities`.`name` = 'all'  ORDER BY `activities`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
=> nil
```

However, when I try to create the record if does not exist I get **SystemStackError: stack level too deep**

```
irb(main):005:0> Activity.where(name: 'all').first_or_create
  Activity Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `activities`.* FROM `activities` WHERE `activities`.`name` = 'all'  ORDER BY `activities`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
SystemStackError: stack level too deep
    from /Users/pippo/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/workspace.rb:80
```

Am I missing something here?

Thanks

Comment: I have seen this same behavior intermittently in my application. I added some tracing code and was able to tentatively determine that the loop is occurring in calls to ```#rollback!```, but at this point I am not certain. Have you found out any additional information about the problem you are having? I'm using Ruby 2.1.5 on Rails 4.1.6